# can not set tooltip dynamically for each highlighted dates in datepicker

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have done highlights for some dates using jquery datepicker calendar.My problem is, I am trying to give tooltips for each date which is highlighted but i can not achieve!.

The code i tried,

```
beforeShowDay: function(date) {
    var highlightdays=["2014-11-20", "2014-11-21", "2014-11-24", "2014-11-25"];
    var whosebday=["mani-bday","john-bday","saro-bday","mikel-bday"];
    var y = date.getFullYear().toString(); // get full year
    var m = (date.getMonth() + 1).toString(); // get month.
    var d = date.getDate().toString(); // get Day
    //alert(m.length);
    if(m.length == 1){ m = '0' + m; } // append zero(0) if single digit
    if(d.length == 1){ d = '0' + d; } // append zero(0) if single digit
    //var currDate = y+'-'+m+'-'+d;


for (var i = 0; i < highlightdays.length; i++) {

  if($.inArray(y + '-' + (m) + '-' + d,disabledDays) != -1) {
  //alert("i value"+i);
  return [true, 'cssdate', 'Today bday for:'+whosebday[i]];

     }
        var day = date.getDay();
        return [(day != 0), ''];//Disable all sundays


        }
        return [true];

}
```

I guess the problem is `i` value does not increase in `whosebday[i].`

**Note :** output is, mani-bday([0]) only come for all dates.
someone tell me where i am wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is in using `for` loop and `$.inArray` inside. `$.inArray` gives you the index of the date if found or `-1` otherwise. Your loop always hit a `return` statement. So it is always performing one and only one iteration. Hence why you always get `i = 0`.

Get rid of the loop and just return `true` if found with the corresponding index returned by `$.inArray`. Refactoring a little bit your code:

```
beforeShowDay: function(date) {
    var y = date.getFullYear().toString(); // get full year
    var m = (date.getMonth() + 1).toString(); // get month.
    var d = date.getDate().toString(); // get Day
    if(m.length == 1){ m = "0" + m; } // append zero(0) if single digit
    if(d.length == 1){ d = "0" + d; } // append zero(0) if single digit

    var ymd = y + '-' + (m) + '-' + d;
    var i = $.inArray(ymd, highlightdays);
    if (i != -1) {
        return [true, "cssdate", whosebday[i]];
    }

    var day = date.getDay();
    return [day != 0, ''];//Disable all sundays
}
```

See [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/stwexv8t/)